# Getting package.json/package-lock.json sync error when pushing to Heroku

Tags: node.js, npm, heroku, package.json

When I push my app to heroku using:

```
git push heroku main
```

I get this error:

```
remote:        npm ERR! cipm can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Invalid: lock file's fs@0.0.1-security does not satisfy fs@*
remote:        npm ERR! Invalid: lock file's http@0.0.1-security does not satisfy http@*
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.hcgsN/_logs/2022-06-02T06_22_59_162Z-debug.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
```

Regarding the `fs` and `http` packages, here is the relevant part of `"dependencies"` in `package.json`:

```
"fs": "*",
"http": "*",
```

And here is how those packages are listed in `package-lock.json`:

In `"dependencies"`:

```
"fs": "*",
"http": "*",
```

In the longer list of module definitions:

```
"fs": {
  "version": "0.0.1-security",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/fs/-/fs-0.0.1-security.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-3XY9e1pP0CVEUCdj5BmfIZxRBTSDycnbqhIOGec9QYtmVH2fbLpj86CFWkrNOkt/Fvty4KZG5lTglL9j/gJ87w=="
},
```

...

```
"http": {
  "version": "0.0.1-security",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/http/-/http-0.0.1-security.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-RnDvP10Ty9FxqOtPZuxtebw1j4L/WiqNMDtuc1YMH1XQm5TgDRaR1G9u8upL6KD1bXHSp9eSXo/ED+8Q7FAr+g=="
},
```

How do I sync these up?  Is `"*"` or `"0.0.1-security"` correct?

I have already tried deleting `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` and then running `npm install`.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the versions in `package.json` to `"0.0.1-security"` and that solved it.

Comment: 9 months later, but imma say for anyone who came here off of Google that you might as well remove it instead, cuz the `0.0.1-security` indicates the package name is being held for security and doesn't actually contain anything useful